# Redundant assignment in Map's putIfAbsent implementation

Tags: java

Looking at the implementation of the default method `putIfAbsent` in the interface `Map`,

```
default V putIfAbsent(K key, V value) {
    V v = get(key);
    if (v == null) {
        v = put(key, value);
    }

    return v;
}
```

I wonder why the assignment

```
v = put(key, value);
```

was done there instead of simply discarding the returned value? This assignment seems unnecessary because `v` is already `null`, and that is what the `put` method, according to its contract, always returns in this case.

Comment: My guess is that it accounts for possibility of a race condition. This method is not an atomic action. The key value association may have been updated in between the `get` and `put` calls

Comment: I thought about concurrency over-cautions, but the phrase "The default implementation makes no guarantees about synchronization or atomicity properties of this method" in the documentation of `putIfAbsent` suggests otherwise. Maybe it is an attempt to be on the safe side, as mentioned in answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation is like that because the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) states it should be:

> Implementation Requirements:
>
> The default implementation is equivalent to, for this map:
>
> ```
>  V v = map.get(key);
>  if (v == null)
>      v = map.put(key, value);
>
>  return v;
> ```

But why is it specified like that?  Probably to get reasonably well-defined behavior in the presence of race conditions that *cannot* be addressed<sup>1</sup>.

First, here's what the javadoc says about it.

> The default implementation makes no guarantees about synchronization or atomicity properties of this method. Any implementation providing atomicity guarantees must override this method and document its concurrency properties.

So how will the above implementation behave?

1. If there is no race with another thread mutating that map entry, it will either return `null` or the previous value (without updating the map).
2. If there is a race and another thread updates the entry *immediately* after the `get` call, then the `map.put` call will NOT return `null`.  Instead, it will actually return the value that the other thread inserted.  And that value will be returned to the caller.

Note that this is not exactly in conformance with the primary description for the `putIfAbsent` method.  But this is excused by the "no guarantees" statement.  And furthermore, it kind of makes sense.

Is this useful?  Well ... probably yes, if the actual `Map` method is thread safe.  Because, if the calling code wanted to look, this would allow it to detect that a race had occurred and (if it made sense in the context of the overall application design) try to do something about it.

<sup>1 - The race conditions cannot be addressed in a default method which has no knowledge of the behavior of implementation classes.  They could be addressed in the implementation classes themselves ... by overriding the  method to have atomic properties, for example.  And the method spec in the `Map` javadocs clearly flag this possibility.</sup>

---

But the bottom line is that that supposedly redundant assignment is there because the spec clearly says that it should be there.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better design decision to change the line `v = put(key, value);` to `if (put(key, value) != null) throw new ConcurrentModificationException();`?

Comment: Nope.   A concurrent collection doesn't throw that exception.   And besides, as I explained, the specified behavior is predictable and useful.  But it really doesn't alter anything debating if it *could have been* designed better.

Comment: But `computeIfAbsent` method has only difference of mappingFunction(vs directValue). Everything else about that method is same including javadoc and disclamers. But that returns new value. Looks like a terrible decision in putIfAbsent to make a half baked attempt to handle concurrency bugs in upper layer application logic.

Comment: Your comment is not apropos.  This question is not about `computeIfAbsent`.

Answer (score 3):

It must always return the old value.

If the map is accessed by multiple threads, the value returned by `put` may differ from the value returned by `get`, so assigning to `v` ensures better behavior.

Of course, the code isn't great for handling multi-threaded access, so any valid thread-safe implementation overrides the method to do it better, but this is the best that a generic default implementation can achieve.

Comment: IMO this is a poor implementation decision. If the value from `put` is different from `get`, then the method still updates the key-value pair, and further, the return value is non-null, which normally indicates that the `put` did not actually happen.

Comment: It is not an implementation decision.  It is a specification decision.  See my answer.